# Next.js: Links inside dropdown menu not working

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, next.js, next-router

I'm trying to enable language selection in Next.js via a dropdown menu. If the links aren't nested inside the `select` tag, they're working fine. As soon as they are though, they're not responding anymore. I'm assuming this is because of a missing event handler and I think that the solution could be rather simple, but I just can't get it to work.

Would be great if someone could have a look at this. Also I'm not looking for a solution to just switch between two languages via a ternary operator, as I'd like to use the logic for future projects with more than two languages. It is also important for me to stick to the `select` tag, as this makes the most sense for a selection of languages and provides better accessibility.

This is working ✅

```js
{router.locales.map((language) => (
  <Link
    href={router.asPath}
    locale={language}
    scroll={false}
    key={language}
  >
  <button type='button'>
    {language === 'en' ? 'EN' : language === 'de' ? 'DE' : null}
  </button>
  </Link>
))}
```

This is not working ❌

```js
<select name='languages' id='language-select'>
  {router.locales.map((language) => (
    <Link
      href={router.asPath}
      locale={language}
      scroll={false}
      key={language}
    >
      <option value={language}>
        {language === 'en'
          ? 'EN'
          : language === 'de'
          ? 'DE'
          : null}
      </option>
    </Link>
  ))}
</select>
```

Thank you very much in advance for taking the time to read this and trying to help me, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you absolutely need to stick with `select`, rather than relying on `next/link` you should listen to the `select`'s `onChange` event and trigger a route change with `next/router` instead.

```js
const SomePage = () => {
    const router = useRouter()

    const onSelectChange = (e) => {
        const locale = e.target.value;
        router.push(router.asPath, router.asPath, {
            locale,
            scroll: false 
        })
    }

    return (
        // ...
        <select name="languages" id="language-select" onChange={onSelectChange}>
            {router.locales.map((language) => (
                <option value={language}>
                    {language === "en" ? "EN" : language === "de" ? "DE" : null}
                </option>
            ))}
        </select>
        // ...
    )
}
```